# How to calculate window width based on getBoundingClientRectAsync values of another element?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, amp-html, web-worker, getboundingclientrect

Is it possible to calculate viewport or window width based on `getBoundingClientRectAsync` values of element which is in virtual DOM?

Running JS in web worker (amp-script):

```
let button = document.querySelector('.tooltip-trigger');

async function addTooltip(event) {

    tooltipElem = document.createElement('span'); 
    document.body.appendChild(tooltipElem);

    let coordsTrigger = await target.getBoundingClientRectAsync();

    // How to get right offset?
    let windowWidth = coordsTrigger.left + coordsTrigger.width;
    console.log(windowWidth);
    
}
```

Target Element (wrapped in amp-script):

```
<amp-script layout="fill" script="tooltip-async"><span class="tooltip-trigger"></span></amp-script>
```

[image]

The half working solution is to use `window.innerWidth`. Half working, because `window.innerWidth` value changes only after page reload, and is not changing on `resize` or any other event for some reason. Probably because it is running in amp-script web-worker DOM and not in main;

**coordsTrigger** out:

```
bottom: 383.65625
height: 24
left: 122.59375
right: 201.640625
top: 359.65625
width: 79.046875
x: 359.65625
y: 122.59375
```